# Dune-SDK-Unable to parse query or install Dune-sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, dune

I'm trying to retrieve results from Dune Analytics. I have already retrieved the Dune API.
However, I'm unable to query it.
Can someone help?
I'm also unable to install Dune-sdk and can't find the discord server as well.

I'm trying to retrieve results from Dune Analytics. I have already retrieved the Dune API.
However, I'm unable to query it.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "retrieved the Dune API"? You mean you have generated an API key or? Also curious which "Dune-sdk" are you trying to install?

In general every query on Dune UI can be turned into an endpoint (like in this gif https://app.arcade.software/share/8B1oBaaI9LjLubSVjjc9)

If you are using Python would recommend doing pip install dune-client (repo here https://github.com/duneanalytics/dune-client)

API specific docs can be found here https://dune.com/docs/api/api-reference/

---

Curious what you are trying to do? Perhaps I can help point you towards the right direction